# Soft Light. Photoshop vs Blender

Tags: compositing-nodes, color-management

I'm trying to move my image processing workflow from photoshop to blender. And I would like to get identical results using basic techniques for different image editors. One of the tricks I often use is highlighting shadows. Here's how I do it in photoshop.

1. open the image and use the sRGB color space.
2. Create a "Curves" layer
3. Set a similar curve as shown in the screenshot for Blender.
4. Apply the blending mode for the Curves layer "Soft Light"

As a result, I get the lightened shadows that I will need for the next processing steps

Now I'm trying to do the same thing in blender but with the help of nodes in compositor. As you can see the result is different from what I get in photoshop. The shadows are not lightened enough. What could be the problem? Are the formulas different? Or am I doing something wrong? You may notice that I am using linear color space for the image and "none" in Display Device. These settings give the closest result to what I get in photoshop. If I use sRGB for these settings, the result is even darker

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]